# Get file path with find without giving filename

Tags: bash, find, command

How can I get the path of a .pid file that is inside a directory.
the code below returns only the file

```
root@linux [/]# ls -l $(find /* -name dovecot | grep var/run) | grep pid
-rw-------  1 root root       5 Nov 28 15:22 master.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess this is what you are looking for:

```
find /var/run -name "*.pid" 2>/dev/null | grep dovecot | xargs ls -l
```

You can also narrow the matches down in the grep command when you specify (parts of) the path inside the filter expression.

Comment: The file name found before was `master.pid` in a directory `dovecot` with `var/run` in the path somewhere.

Comment: Ah, ok, got that wrong. I changed the suggestion. Better like that?

Comment: Better.  It's likely `/var/run` but the original search was under all (non-hidden) directories under `/*` and would find `/usr/adm/var/run/dovcote` as a for instance.

Comment: Ok, sure you can search the whole file system. Just shorten the path inside the find command. But you don't want to do that, do you? It's gonna take forever and creates a huge disk load...

Comment: I don't want to search the whole system — but the OP did.  It's very reasonable to point out that it is a potentially very expensive search (and avoiding searching `/.*` files is barely worth the effort of typing the `*`)...

Answer (score 0):

I think the interpretation of the output must be that the `find` command finds a directory name such as:

```
/var/run/dovecot
```

and you do an `ls -l` on the directory, which lists the files in the directory without any path leading to it.  What you need is to find a reliable way of listing the files in the directory with their full path names.

One way — not I think a good way — of doing it would be:

```
find $(find /* -name dovecot -type d | grep var/run) -type f -name '*.pid' \
     -exec ls -l {} +
```

This uses your first `find` command to get the directories you're interested in, then runs `find` again to find `.pid` files and execs `ls -l` on them.  The `+` notation means that `find` behaves a bit like `xargs`, bunching a lot of file names together into a single run of `ls -l`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /var/run/dovecot/master.pid
```

?

Or :

```
# readlink -f /var/run/dovecot/*.pid
/var/run/dovecot/master.pid
```